# Why do i get errors when i place TextField inside In Row

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to put a Two Textfields on a row so that they align in one row but i seem to be getting the below error,i cant seem to get what i am doing wrong here.Help apreciated.

import "package:flutter/material.dart";

```
void main(){
  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
          title: 'Planet',
          home:Home()
      )
  );
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HomeState();
  }

}


class HomeState extends State<Home>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
            'Weight on Planet x',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.5),
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('images/planet.png',height: 133.0,width: 200.0,),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    controller: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Your weight on Earth',
                        hintText: 'In Pounds',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline)
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Your weight on Earth',
                        hintText: 'In Pounds',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline)
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

I get the following error

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderDecoration#3373c relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving some finite `width` to the `TextField` parent `Container`. By default `TextFields` occupy the entire space made available by their parent which is in this case infinite.

Or, you can use individual `Containers` for each `TextField` if you want them to have custom widths.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use `Expanded` to inform the horizontal size (maximum available).

```
             Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    controller: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Your weight on Earth',
                        hintText: 'In Pounds',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline)),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Your weight on Earth',
                        hintText: 'In Pounds',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
```